# Can't create external data source for MongoDB in SQL Server 2022

Tags: mongodb, polybase, sql-server-2022

I'm following the instructions in [Configure PolyBase to access external data in MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-mongodb?view=sql-server-ver16) for SQL Server 2022, and get the following error when creating the external data source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE mongodb_001
WITH (
      LOCATION = 'mongodb://my.server.name:27030'
     ,CREDENTIAL = mongodb_cred
)

Msg 46530, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
External data sources are not supported with type GENERIC.
```

I took a look at the page's link for [CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=dedicated), however, it doesn't mention a TYPE parameter.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <data_source_name>
WITH
  ( [ LOCATION = '<prefix>://<path>[:<port>]' ]
    [ [ , ] CONNECTION_OPTIONS = '<key_value_pairs>'[,...]]
    [ [ , ] CREDENTIAL = <credential_name> ]
    [ [ , ] PUSHDOWN = { ON | OFF } ]
  )
[ ; ]
```

I do see that SQL Server 2016 required the TYPE parameter, and that they say to check the specific syntax for your SQL Server version.  We are on a 2022 evaluation version (see below for the full version info), and the above command was copied from the above link, so I think I have the up-to-date format.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard Evaluation 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: )
```

Also, I verified that PolyBase is installed:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('IsPolyBaseInstalled') AS IsPolyBaseInstalled; 
returns 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... finally ran across [this post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/03/16/sql-server-polybase-error-msg-46530-external-data-sources-are-not-supported-with-type-generic/) where they said that even though the IsPolyBaseInstalled query may return 1, you need to do this:

```
exec sp_configure @configname = 'polybase enabled', @configvalue = 1;
```

followed by:

```
RECONFIGURE
```

Once I did that, I was able to create the external data source.